# Comando header no PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc, header

Estou tentando criar um sistema de MVC simples no qual tenho a seguinte estrutura de pasta:

```
Arquivos de Código-Fonte - Pasta
  Servlet - Pasta
     UserServlet.class.php
  Controller - Pasta
     UserController.class.php
  Model - Pasta
     DAO - Pasta
        UserDAO.class.php
     VO - Pasta
        UserVO.class.php
  View - Pasta
    userForm.php
  index.php
```

Eu preciso fazer com que meu `index.php` chame a classe `Servlet`, para isso coloquei o seguinte código:

```
<?php
    header('Location : Servlet/UserServlet.class.php?action=goHome');
?>
```

Mas o problema é que não acontece nada e eu preciso chamar a classe `Servlet` para nela eu tratar qual método vou usar. Se alguém souber uma solução, um modo para eu conseguir fazer uma requisição HTTP na `Servlet` vai me ajudar muito.

Comment: Dá algum erro ? Atenção que a chamada a função `header` não pode ser feita depois de ter sido escrito html na página, caso contrario não irá funcionar.

Comment: Você está apenas declarando a classe  ou também instancia a mesma no próprio script? pois se você disse que a operação não é executada, imagino que você espere então que o script faça algo, logo deve haver a instância da classe `Servlet` sendo chamada lá...

Comment: Você quer chamar a class pra trabalhar com ela ou redirecionar a pagina para a class?

Answer (score 0):

Você não vai conseguir fazer isso com header('Location: '), pq quando se trabalha com classes precisa instanciar um objeto e chamar um método.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
require 'Servlet/UserServlet.class.php';

$class = 'UserServlet';
$method = 'goHome';

$class = new $class;
call_user_func(array($class, $method));
```

Há alguns anos eu criei um projeto parecido com essa sua ideia, chamei de Jiraya Framework, e usei para trabalhar com projetos pequenos usando MVC e urls amigáveis, dá uma olhada https://github.com/evandrobalmant/jiraya-mvc/